# Getting outdated version of a Maven project resource in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I inherited a project and I stumbled upon this snippet of code which is trying to load a resource in `/src/main/resources` using the URL given by `getSystemResource` and getting the stream of it:

```
try
{
    is = new URL(this.getClass().getSystemResource("checker/config.default.xml").toString()).openStream();
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, this.configFile);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    log.error("Could not load default config from API resources!", e);
}
finally
{
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}
```

But after I made some changes to the config file, the snippet of code didn't do what it was supposed to do and still fetched the now outdated version of the config. I also tried with `getResource`:

```
ClassLoader classloader = getClass().getClassLoader();
is = new URL(classloader.getResource("checker/config.default.xml").toString()).openStream();
```

and finally settled on `getResourceAsStream`

```
ClassLoader classloader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("checker/config.default.xml");
```

To no avail, although it works when I test the code locally on eclipse and I'm not getting a `null` when tests are using the tool in Jenkins, the tool still use an outdated configuration from a few releases ago.

Also I'm pretty confident that the path I'm using in the method is right. I tried `/src/main/resources/checker/config.default.xml` or `/checker/config.default.xml` but it gives me `NullPointerException`.

**EDIT - additional information:**
I build locally with Eclipse the jar as Jenkins would do and checked that the correct version of the resource was packed in it too. Also the test workspace is cleaned after each Jenkins run.

I'm at a loss on how to make sure that it always fetch the latest version of the file. Is there an alternative method that I missed? Is it some kind of weird cache issue I'm not aware of?

Comment: `"logchecker/logchecker-config.default.xml").toString()` is exactly the same as `"logchecker/logchecker-config.default.xml"`.Don't write pointless code.

Comment: First you should never read resources file based ...better go via `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/logchecker/logcheker-config.default.xml")` furthermore check if you start with `/` which means starting in the root location of your `src/main/resources`.Is the correct file in the resulting `jar` packaged?

Comment: @EJP `("logchecker/logchecker-config.default.xml").toString()` is exactly the same as `"logchecker/logchecker-config.default.xml"` but `getResource("logchecker/logchecker-config.default.xml")` sends an `URL` back thus the need of `toString()`

Comment: Did you run the clean goal on Jenkins? What happens if you manually delete the workspace of the Jenkins job before starting the build?

Comment: @khmarbaise I did a test build in my eclipse and the correct version of the xml was packed in the jar. using a `/`at the beginning of the path leads to a NPE whereas using a "relative" path (relative to `/src/main/resources` as it is a maven project) do retrieve me a file. Although it is always the correct one on Eclipse, it is an older version in my Jenkins test.

Comment: @werner the workspaces are cleaned after each tests using my tool. But that wouldn't help me much as this resource is packed in a jar and not available in the jenkins project if I understood my admin correctly.

Comment: Does your maven build work correctly?

Comment: @khmarbaise I found out that an older version of the resource was available on a related project. Wouldn't have thought to check if it weren't for you. I may write this information as the answer, once I found a good and helpful way to formulate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `checker` project was but one of the dependencies of a bigger project.

What I found out is that the older version of the wanted resource came from another dependency.